# Angular Ivy compatibility issue

Tags: angular, typescript, printing

trying to user ngx-print or ngx-printer in angular 10 but getting errors seems due to Ivy

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r4vmjn?file=src/app/app.module.ts

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.2",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.5",
    "ngx-printer": "^0.8.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": false }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "app",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

**app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgxPrinterModule } from 'ngx-printer/lib/ngx-printer.module';
import { NgxPrintModule } from 'ngx-print/lib/ngx-print.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxPrinterModule.forRoot({printOpenWindow: true}),
    NgxPrintModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**ERROR**

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-print/lib/ngx-print.module' in 'D:\angular print\app\src\app'

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ngx-printer/lib/ngx-printer.module' in 'D:\angular print\app\src\app'

Answer (score 1):

You need to import from `ngx-printer` and `ngx-print`:

```
import { NgxPrinterModule } from 'ngx-printer';
import { NgxPrintModule } from 'ngx-print';
```

[stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mkeqvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: I have a similar error.
I have two libraries, map and shared. In the service of map I import shared like this ```import { entity } from 'shared';``` and when I build map returns this error ```Could not resolve '../../../../../dist/shared/public-api'```.
But as you suggest to @Mubeen my import is right. Do you know why?
Note: I need my library built with enableIvy false and this error appears only when Ivy is false. If I put enableIvy: true the error disappears and build goes successful.